# Parse post request in Python

Tags: python, html, http, parsing

Good day! I have trouble with parsing dynamic element from radio stations website. Here you need the name of the current song

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


songsNameList = []

url = f"https://top-radio.ru/web/russkij-xit"
q = requests.get(url)
result = q.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
songs = soup.select("#se_igra")

for song in songs:
    print(song.find('span'))
    songsNameList.append(song.find('span'))
```

https://top-radio.ru/web/marusya-fm

The name of the song included in [image: gif format] from POST string

[image: Output], that I have

How I can parse this case?

Answer (score 1):

This site uses java script. Beautiful soup is not enough for this. Use Selenium for such a task.
You can read more here.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
Here you can download geckodriver for Firefox.
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Then add to your code these lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'/usr/bin/firefox') #add here in quotes path to your Firefox
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
caps['marionette'] = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=caps, firefox_profile=profile,
                               executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')  ##add here in quotes path to downloaded geckodriver
q = driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Thank you for this way. Once was using solve with browser drivers for other project, this app was not loaded in docker-compose, nginx and remote source. Is there the solves for driverless parsing for more separated, effeccient and close steps for this direction?

Comment: You can use it headless

Comment: Translator gives surprises. I added FirefoxProfile string to code. After launching, app doesn't send the current song

Comment: `profile = FirefoxProfile("/home/ilya/.mozilla/firefox/")` with `print(q)` `Output: None`

Comment: profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() or don`t use profile at all

Comment: With no messages from server, function get None, but in general greate variative method. Rare experience in development